# pandas column transformation

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transform my data that I have a column in this format

```
a = {'Monday': '9:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '9:0-0:0'}
b = {'Monday': '17:30-21:30', 'Wednesday': '17:30'}
df = pd.DataFrame({'hours':[np.nan, a, b],
                   'id':['sdfdad','ddfsfs','sedfws']})
print (df)
                                             hours      id
0                                              NaN  sdfdad
1      {'Monday': '9:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '9:0-0:0'}  ddfsfs
2  {'Monday': '17:30-21:30', 'Wednesday': '17:30'}  sedfws
```

and I want Keys: Monday, Tuesday... as column names and 0-9 as their cell value like this.

```
Monday   Tuesday       Wednesday
9:0-0:0  17:30-21:30   17:30-21:30

yelp_business=pd.read_csv('yelp-dataset/cs_data/business.csv')
```

This the condition right now,
[image]

This is desired.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [mcve], also avoid screenshots, use copy paste instead. At this point this is difficult to help you, we miss a trial input (some lines from the CSV), desired output description.

Comment: Where is the business_id of the data? It looks like you have to transform the data so you have columns of the days by taking the day data out of the objects in the hours column and matching them to the business_id.

Comment: yes actually in my data frame i have a column name hours which have mutiple values in each cell like {'Monday': '9:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '9:0-0:0', 'W...} what I want is to replace hour column with 7 columns named monday tuesday wednesday... and each value presenting a single cell

Comment: @AbdulRafay - Some problem with code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First replace missing values to empty dict in list comprehension and pass to `DataFrame` constructor, last [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) `id` column, also for test mising values is used `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`:

```
c =  ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
L = [x if x == x else {} for x in df['hours']]
df1 = df[['id']].join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index, columns=c))
print (df1)
       id       Monday  Tuesday Wednesday  Thursday  Friday  Saturday  Sunday
0  sdfdad          NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN
1  ddfsfs      9:0-0:0  9:0-0:0       NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN
2  sedfws  17:30-21:30      NaN     17:30       NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN
```

Comment: data = [(type(d) is dict) and d or dict(d) for d in data]
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required      i got this error . there's a problem in this line                                                       
    L = [x if x == x else {} for x in df['hours']]

Comment: @Abdul Rafay What is `print(df['hours'].apply(type))` for non NaNs values? If strings, try `import ast` and `L = [ast.literal_eval(x) if x == x else {} for x in df['hours']]`